# Postgres geolocation points Distance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query to determinate the distances between geolocation points in a Postgres database this is my query

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (latitude - 31.8679), 2) +
POW(69.1 * (-116.6567 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM locations 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance
```

but it give me this error

> ERROR:  column "distance" does not exist
>   LINE 5: HAVING distance < 25

if i remove the part "HAVING distance < 25" the query runs OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok i solve it checking other questions

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
SELECT latitude, longitude,SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - 31.8679), 2) +
POW(69.1 * (-116.6567 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance 
FROM Locations) t
WHERE distance < 1
ORDER BY distance
```

Answer (score 4):

`HAVING` filters `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions, while `WHERE` filters rows. `WHERE` happens before the `SELECT`, therefore the *distance* column is not available to filter on in the `WHERE` clause.

Query 1 could have been written

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (latitude - 31.8679), 2) +
POW(69.1 * (-116.6567 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM locations 
WHERE SQRT(
POW(69.1 * (latitude - 31.8679), 2) +
POW(69.1 * (-116.6567 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) < 25 
ORDER BY distance
```

Using a sub query, the inner query is built before the outer query, and the *t.distance* is therefore available to the outer query.